# How to use date format to get month and year in Yii2

Tags: yii2, date-format

Let's say I have a table

```
Date    Item    Qty
15/1/2016   Item1   10
16/1/2016   Item1   20
16/2/2016   Item1   30
18/2/2016   Item1   10
```

And In the report I want to display like this

```
Month   Qty
01-2016 30
02-2016 40
```

Please tell me how can I do this in Yii2.

I've tried the following in my SearchModel.

```
$query = Productsalesdetails::find()
        ->select(['DATE_FORMAT(date, "%m-%Y"),productname,sum(total) as total'])
        ->groupBy('DATE_FORMAT(date, "%m-%Y")');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the query use letteral select and alias for date_format too..

```
$query = Productsalesdetails::find()
    ->select( 'DATE_FORMAT(date, "%m-%Y") as m_date, productname, sum(total) as total')
    ->groupBy ('m_date, productname');
```

Do the fact you have already the format in select you can use the alias in attributes

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'summaryOptions' => ['class' =>'dfenx_pagination_summary',],
    'pager' => ['options' => ['class'=> 'pagination pull-right']],
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        [
           'attribute' => '', 
           'label' => 'Month',  
           'value' => function ($model) {       
                return $model->m_date;
           },        
        ],
        [
           'attribute' => 'productname', 
           'label' => 'Item',  
        ],
         [
           'attribute' => '', 
           'label' => 'Total',  
           'value' => function ($model) {       
                return $model->total;
           },        
        ],

       ....

    ]);
```

this should work without adding $var in model for alias .. 
otherwise you your model you need

```
class YourModel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
   public $m_date;
   public $total;
   .....
```

Comment: But I need to group by the month. You can see I've grouped it by the month.

Comment: I'm sorry but the question title seems about format .. or are two question in one  ... eventually post the code for select the related data .. you have a model? .. a dataProvider ? .. use a grid view ..

Comment: Yes. My question is not 100% right. I want both the group by as well as date format. I've added my Search Model in the question.

Comment: Getting unknown property: backend\modules\...\models\Productsalesdetails::m_date

Comment: I have update the answer avoiding the m_date name in attribute .try thgis first ... but could be you need proper public var in you model for support the query result i have update the  answer ..

Comment: Working now. Great. Thanks a lot